# How to pass query string parameters to Smartsheet API with node.js?

Tags: node.js, smartsheet-api

I need to get a list of all columns in one request and manual states that I should pass query string parameter:

> Most index endpoints default to a page size of 100 results. If you
>   need all results at once, you should specify the includeAll=true query
>   string parameter.

Here is that I tried:

```
var options = {
    sheetId: 2252168947361668,
    includeAll: true
};

smartsheet.sheets.getColumns(options)
    .then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

But it returns me only first 100 columns.
How should I pass query string parameters to `smartsheet-api` from node.js?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **includeAll** parameter is a query string parameter so it must be included in the **queryParameters** object. The following should work for you:

```
var options = {
    sheetId: 2252168947361668,
    queryParameters: {
      includeAll: true
    }
};

smartsheet.sheets.getColumns(options)
    .then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```